# How to use the Wolfram Language or another tool to find a second order pde solution with initial conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematica, symbolic-computation

I want to find a solution the Cauchy problem using the Wolfram Language or some other tool.

I have next task:
$$
3\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + 8\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} - 3\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} - 60\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 20\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0,\\
u(x,0) = -4e^{2x},~ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,0) = -9xe^{2x}
$$

So, I tried to run this using wolfram notebook:

```
weqn = 3D[u[x,y],{x,2}] + 8D[u[x,y],{x}, {y}] -3D[u[x,y],{y,2}] - 60D[u[x,y],x] +20D[u[x,y],y] == 0
ic = {u[x,0] ==-4e^(2x), Derivative[0,1][u][x,0] == -9xe^(2x)}
sol = DSolve[{weqn, ic},u,{x,y}]
```

but I got very big and strange answer (I couldn't even see it in full), may be I did something wrong. The answer of task on a piece of paper is prettier.

And so, can I somehow solve similar tasks using Wolfram or another tool?

Comment: Change $-4e^{2x}$ in $-4E^{2x}$ and correct $xe^{2x}$ in $x\;E^{2x}$ with a space between $x$ and $E$. I got $u(x,y)=-e^{2 x+6 y} \left(9 x y+12 y^2-24 y+4\right)$

Comment: @Raffaele, Ok, using `E` instead `e` is more correct?

Comment: It's the syntax of Mathematica, just like you have to write Pi for $\pi$ or Sin[x] for $\sin x$

Comment: @Raffaele, Thank you! Now it works! 
And may be you know how can I write correctly next task in Wolfram?
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} = 0, ~ u(x,x^2) = 0, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,x^2) = \sqrt{|x|}, ~ |x| < 1 $$
I write this, but it don't work: 

`weqn = D[u[x,y],x,y] == 0` --- 


`ic = {u[x,x^2] == 0, Derivative[0,1][u][x,x^2] == Sqrt[Abs[x]], Abs[x] < 1}` --- 

`sol = DSolve[{weqn, ic},u,{x,y}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in the comments under my question. The correct code should be like this:

```
weqn = 3D[u[x,y],{x,2}] + 8D[u[x,y],{x}, {y}] -3D[u[x,y],{y,2}] - 60D[u[x,y],x] +20D[u[x,y],y] == 0
ic = {u[x,0] ==-4E^(2x), Derivative[0,1][u][x,0] == -9x E^(2x)}
sol = DSolve[{weqn, ic},u,{x,y}]
```

You should use `E` instead `e`, because mathematica.